# How to play audio from an RTSP stream in python

Tags: python, audio, pyqt, streaming, rtsp

I have this simple script which displays a video from an rtsp stream (this part works well), i also create an audio object (which when printed shows this: "<av.AudioStream #1 aac at 16000Hz, mono, fltp at 0x1bf4961fb80>"), how do i play the audio through this for the user to hear?

```
import sys
import av
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


class VideoStreamWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rtsp_url_local):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('RTSP Stream')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 640, 480)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel('Waiting for video stream...')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Open the RTSP stream
        self.container = av.open(rtsp_url_local)
        self.stream = self.container.streams.video[0]

        self.audio = self.container.streams.audio[0]
        print(self.audio)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_image)
        self.timer.start(16.5)

        self.audio_timer = QTimer()
        self.audio_timer.timeout.connect(self.update_audio)
        self.audio_timer.start(16.5)

    def update_audio(self):
        return

    def update_image(self):
        for frame in self.container.decode(self.stream):
            img = frame.to_image()  # Convert frame to PIL image
            img = img.convert("RGB")
            data = np.array(img)
            qimg = QImage(data, data.shape[1], data.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qimg)
            self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            break  # Only process one frame per timeout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    rtsp_url = 'rtsp://192.168.1.18:554/video=0,audio=0'  # Example RTSP URL
    video_stream_widget = VideoStreamWidget(rtsp_url)
    video_stream_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I dont really know what to try as im a beginner in audio in general and specifically with python-av

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the QtMultimedia module should be able to play rtsp based streams (but it actually depends on the underlying OS capabilities for Qt5). If it works and you only need playback, there's really no need for python-av, as showing an image of a frame is much simpler than playing back an audio stream, especially if you also need proper sync. Alternatively, switch to Qt6.

Comment: @musicamante id gladly move over to pyqt6 if it solves anything, rn im using av because im able to get to only around 150 ms delay and the delay is critical for me. from my experience with opencv for example you cant really get below 500 ms, in pyqt6 can you get down to those type of numbers? Nevertheless, how do you play audio in qt6 from an rtsp stream?

Comment: The delay can depend on many aspects, including a/v sync. As said, if you need audio *and* video, you cannot rely on two different systems to play streams, because they'll never be in sync (and since delay is critical for you, I assume that accurate a/v sync will be too). Try the classes of the QtMultimedia module in Qt5 and see if it's able to play streams with rtsp protocol on your system. Also check if the source is able to stream on other network protocols (if it supports any http[s] protocol, you may only need to install codecs on your OS in case it doesn't support the format natively).